# Dealing with bugs that only appear right after boot

Tags: python, windows, debugging, race-condition, boot

I dealt with a bug today that only appeared when I ran my program right after booting my computer.  The cold start exposed a race condition which triggered the bug.  I managed to fix it, but it took a long time because I had to reboot my machine several times to figure out what was going on.  Can anybody suggest better ways of debugging problems like this in the future?  Can I somehow quickly put the computer into a "just booted" state?

Running Python 2.6 on Windows XP.

Comment: Was the cause a race in operations that happen on boot or the cold caches on startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use virtual machine (f.e. VirtualBox) and *save state* (make snapshot) just before booting is finished. Test freely and restore *just booted* state according to your needs.

Comment: anyway, even booting bare winxp in virtualbox is on my core2duo laptop so fast that you may not need snapshots :-)

Answer (score 3):

Run it inside a virtual machine.